# Java regular expressions: ignore all characters until certain character. regex

Tags: java, regex, character

I am writing a java program to download PDFs automatically from a website. My program reads through an excel file, and downloads the PDF for every account number in the excel file. In the browser, the account is selected from a menu, however, the menu has the format of # storenumber - accountnumber (ex. # 1234 - 987654321). I do not have access to the store numbers. A simple solution would be just to ignore the first x characters, but some of the store numbers are different length so this does not work.

Is it possible for java to disregard all the characters before the  -  , and if it is could you write out this expression.

I am using it with selenium and firefox webdriver, making it harder to simply seperate and save the string. Meaning I do NOT have the string in memory, it is coming from the browser.

This is what my code would look like IF i had the store numbers (but i dont).

`new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_main_ddlAssocAccountNumbers"))).selectByVisibleText(storeNum + " - " + accountNum);`

Any other solutions or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Torbir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the format `# storenumber - accountnumber` is fixed better use a `split()`

```
accountNum = accountNum.split(" - ")[1];
```

***EDIT :***
As per your updated post and comments, I think you're looking to make a partial match on just the user account number while using Selenium's `selectByVisibleText()` method which does not accept any wildcards or regular expressions.

But here's how you can achieve this behaviour by doing a sub-string match using `contains()`:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(
                    By.id("ctl00_main_ddlAssocAccountNumbers")));
List<WebElement> listOfOptions = select.getOptions();
for (WebElement option : listOfOptions) {
    String storeAndAcctNum = option.getText();
    if (storeAndAcctNum.contains(accountNum)) { // if sub-string matches
        select.selectByVisibleText(storeAndAcctNum); // fire select as usual
        break; // out of the loop
    }
}
```